# Android Directory for rosjava

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to install the android directory in the rosjava directory by using
*"hg clone [https://code.googlecode.com/p/rosjava.android/"](https://code.googlecode.com/p/rosjava.android/%22)*
However this doesn't work as the connection gets timed out.

Is there another way to get the android directory?

-Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12262/android-directory-for-rosjava/) by [Jake_62](https://answers.ros.org/users/1504/jake_62/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like google code is changing their infrastructure layout.  According to the [project website instructions](http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/checkout) the correct command to use is:

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/rosjava/
```

I do see a lot of references to the url style in the question in our documentation, but the servers are unresponsive.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1